# c++ dereference pointed object and pass into a function as reference, value is changed

Tags: c++

Dear experienced c++ expert:

In recent coding process, there is a trick problem associated with reference and
dereference operation.

```
typedef io::SequenceDataAccess<DNA_N>     read_access_type;
```

here is class constructor:

```
AlignmentData( // ignored some arguments 
              const io::SequenceDataHost*   read_data_batch
             )
{
read_access_type read_data_access( *read_data_batch );
......
}
```

in a debug session, I set a breakpoint at the function body(the unique line), the 
value of read_data_batch(a pointer) is 0x7fff9a0489a0, and print the other state info:

```
(gdb) print read_data_batch
$7 = (const bxtbio::io::SequenceDataHost *) **0x7fff9a0489a0**
(gdb) print *read_data_batch
$8 = (bxtbio::io::SequenceData) {<bxtbio::io::SequenceData> = 
{<bxtbio::io::SequenceDataInfo> = {m_alphabet = bxtbio::DNA_N, 
m_n_seqs = 250, m_n_segments = 0, m_name_stream_len = 16392, 
m_sequence_stream_len = 25000, m_sequence_stream_words = 3125, 
......
```

but when I step into the constructor of class SequenceDataAccess,

shown as below:

```
NVBIO_HOST_DEVICE NVBIO_FORCEINLINE 
SequenceDataAccess(const SequenceDataT& data):m_data(data)
```

the argument data's state:

```
(gdb) print &data
$9 = (const bxtbio::io::SequenceDataViewCore<unsigned int const*, 
unsigned int const*, char const*, char const*> *) **0x7fffa0aacb50**

(gdb) print data 
$10 = (const bxtbio::io::SequenceDataViewCore<unsigned int const*, unsigned int const*, char const*, char const*> &) @0x7fffa0aacb50: {<bxtbio::io::SequenceDataInfo> = {m_alphabet = bxtbio::PROTEIN, m_n_seqs = 0, m_n_segments = 0, m_name_stream_len = 0, m_sequence_stream_len = 0, m_sequence_stream_words = 0, m_has_qualities = 0, .......
```

My Questions:

1. shouldn't data has the same address as the  read_data_batch which is
   passed in the copy-constructor?
2. why are the data member's values all changed? What are the possible
   reasons?

this code is running in a multiple threads environment.

Thanks.

Here is a small invoke chain code excerpt:

```
// file1.cpp
void MapSpliceWorker::align(io::HostOutputBatchSE *cpu_batch)
{
    log_info(stderr, "MapSpliceWorker::align called cpu_batch.count = %d\n",cpu_batch->count);

    for (uint32 c = 0; c < cpu_batch->count; c++) {
        AlignmentData alignment = get(*cpu_batch, c);   // Here is the entrypoint invocation
    }
}

// file2.cpp
AlignmentData get(HostOutputBatchSE& batch, const uint32 aln_id)
{
    const uint32 read_id = batch.read_ids.size() ?
                           batch.read_ids[ aln_id ] : aln_id;
   // construct a AlignmentData object and return
    return AlignmentData(&batch.alignments[aln_id],
                         batch.mapq[aln_id],
                         aln_id,
                         read_id,
                         batch.read_data,
                         &batch.cigar,
                         &batch.mds);
}
// file3.h
struct AlignmentData
{
    AlignmentData(const Alignment*              _aln,
                  const uint32                  _mapq,
                  const uint32                  _aln_id,
                  const uint32                  _read_id,
                  const io::SequenceDataHost*   read_data_batch,
                  const HostCigarArray*         cigar_array,
                  const HostMdsArray*           mds_array)
        : valid(true),
          aln(_aln),
          aln_id(_aln_id),
          read_id(_read_id),
          mapq(_mapq),
          read_data_batch_p(read_data_batch),
          cigar_array_p(cigar_array),
          mds_array_p(mds_array)
    {
        read_access_type read_data_access( *read_data_batch );   // up to now, read_data_batch has valid states
    }
};

// file4. h
template <
    Alphabet  SEQUENCE_ALPHABET_T,
    typename  SequenceDataT = ConstSequenceDataView>
struct SequenceDataAccess
{
    /// constructor
    NVBIO_HOST_DEVICE NVBIO_FORCEINLINE 
SequenceDataAccess(const SequenceDataT& data) 
: m_data( data )   // here the data's states is cleaned and the address is not same as read_data_batch in previous context.
    {
      #if !defined(NVBIO_DEVICE_COMPILATION) || defined(NVBIO_CUDA_DEBUG)
        assert( m_data.m_alphabet == SEQUENCE_ALPHABET );  
        // failed by this assert
      #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your program invoked [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If some piece of the program writes out-of-bounds (corrupting heap or stack) the results are unpredictable.

Whenever you see inexplicable things like this in your code, you should be thinking of UB elsewhere.

You could...

- Start with minimal code and gradually add code until the problem appears¹
- use a memory checker/instrumenter (valgrind, rational purify)
- use sanitizers (much the same effects, eg. `-fsanitize=address,undefined` for GCC/clang)

> Keep in mind that debugging optimized code can be disorienting because the compiler may re-arranges code out-of-order and optimize variables out.
>
> Using a debug (unoptimized) build can help, BUT you might not see the UB then

¹ This approach is haphazard, because UB means you might not see the problem when it exists (it's *undefined*: It might just appear to execute normally)

Comment: I am sorry for my carelessness. I finally found a implicit type conversion operator which constructed a new empty object and returned to the caller. That's why the data looks changed, actually it is a new created one initialized with empty values. I am working on a existing project and not familiar with each code line. This is a program running on GPU, so, object should be converted to a device version when transferred to the device from host memory. this empty object is just an intermediate status.

Answer (score -2):

Pass by reference just allows you to work with the variables without derefrencing them. It's still like passing a pointer. A perma-derefrenced pointer.

When you take an objects reference you are taking its address. A pointer is just an objects address. So a reference and pointer to the same object have the same value. The difference between a reference and a pointer is that references are immutable and pointers are mutable. There's a lot more little differences but that's a pretty big one.

Comment: I found the value of the data is cleared,  while read_data_batch has all correct data member.

Comment: I just figured my answer was pretty good if you are really doing what you said in the title. Are you writing the derefrenced pointer to a tmp variable before referencing it? If not then your values will be changed if the function changes the value of that parameter.

Comment: Thanks,DeezNuts. I did not write the dereferenced pointer to a tmp variable and the function did not make any change to the parameter, just call assert to check the value, as indicated by the code. m_data.m_alphabet should be same as that of read_data_batch but it is now cleared. I doubt  it is a new created empty object. but not found any code to do this construction.

Comment: @user8210143 your talking about things irrelevant to the post. The post passes a pointer and the question is about corruption/unexpected changes.

Comment: I am sorry to you all. Finally I found it is a implicit type conversion operator which created a new empty data object, which led to a "unexpected" behavior. Thank your for your concern.